# Circular progress bar in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, progress-bar

In referencing https://github.com/asimmittal/SillyUIControls/tree/master/CircularProgressBarWP8 for a fun new implementation of a progress indicator, I would like to adapt the circular progreessbar control to Windows Phone 8. But when i downloaded the project and rebuild-ed , it gave compile time error. error is as follow

The property 'BgBrush' does not exist on the type 'CircularProgressBar' in the XML namespace 'clr-namespace:CircularProgressBarWP8'.    E:\app\samples\WindowsProjects-master\CircularProgressBarWP8\CircularProgressBarWP8\MainPage.xaml   20  65  CircularProgressBarWP8

even when go to defination of it. it takes me to the definition but does not compile . it gives same error on FgBrush and HoleBrush .i  dont know any clue why is this error. so what is the problem can anybody tell

Comment: The property has no getter, it may be the cause of the error

Comment: ok done thanks i have added get property as you said and it worked @KooKiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the listed properties have no getter. Make sure to add one before referencing them in the XAML.